# Groovy intent API Call

Tags: groovy

Can some one provide sample script to call external API.
Need to use basic authentication and get the response.

Comment: You need to give more details. Is it a web API, a DLL or what ?

Comment: yes i want to call Web Api by including session id and csrf token

Answer (score 0):

Since there are numerous libraries out there to do HTTP requests it's hard to know what your environment is and if I have to do this in a specific library API.  So I'm going to assume you are using Java 11 and just do the newest HTTP API from the JDK.

```
import java.net.http.*

class BasicAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
      String username
      String password
     
      BasicAuthenticator( String username, String password ) {
         this.username = username
         this.password = password
      }

      @Override
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password.toCharArray());
      }
  }
}

HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .GET()
  .uri(new URI("https://postman-echo.com/basic-auth"))
  .build()

HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient
   .newBuilder()
   .authenticator(new BasicAuthenticator("postman", "password"))
   .build()
   .send( req, BodyHandlers.ofString() )
```